# How do I use "BigDecimal" in Java for my specific code?

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I'm very new to programming in Java. I have been given an assignment in my school to solve the following exercise:

"Create two variables, each containing a number. Put out a message that shows how often the second number fits into the first one, and the rest (if there is one)" [I hope the wording is clear. I'm translating this from my native language german into english]

Now in general, I have solved the exercise like this (using Netbeans):

```
double numberOne = 10, numberTwo = 35.55;
double result, rest;
String conversion, numberOutput;

result = numberTwo / numberOne;
conversion = Double.toString(result);
int indexOfComma = conversion.indexOf(".");
numberOutput = conversion.substring(0, indexOfComma);
rest = numberTwo % numberOne;

System.out.println("The second number fits " + numberOutput + 
" times into the first one. The rest is: " + rest);
```

With the numbers provided, the system pops out this message:

"The second number fits 3 times into the first one. The rest is: 5.549999999999997"

I don't like the rounding error for the rest. I expected it to give out "5.55" like a human would type or write it. After a bit of googling around it seems that something called "BigDecimal" is the solution to my problem, but the explanations I found of how to implement this in Java go wayyy over my head.

Would you be so kind as to show me exactly where and how I need to use BigDecimal in the above code to get the desired output? I would also be happy to see any alternative solutions you can think of.

Comment: `BigDecimal` doesn't seem relevant to your problem at all. You just need to learn how to format your output data.

Comment: My reading of "fit into" is the other way. `10` (first number) fits into `35.55` (second number) three times.

Comment: @John3136 Could you elaborate? To my understanding, formating would only make it look "prettier", like cutting off to only the last 2 digits after the comma, but wouldn't help me with fixing the rounding error.

Comment: I might not have been precise enough. An example: Let's say you want to produce apple juice. For a full bottle of juice, you need 10 apples (numberOne). You have 35 apples (numberTwo). So you can take 30 apples to produce 3 full bottles, and the rest of 5 apples to produce a half bottle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BigDecimal version of your code:

```java
BigDecimal numberOne = new BigDecimal("10");
BigDecimal numberTwo = new BigDecimal("35.55");
BigDecimal[] divRem = numberTwo.divideAndRemainder(numberOne);
System.out.println("The second number fits " + divRem[0].stripTrailingZeros().toPlainString() + 
                   " times into the first one. The rest is: " + divRem[1].stripTrailingZeros().toPlainString());
```

*Output*

```
The second number fits 3 times into the first one. The rest is: 5.55
```

Comment: But the first number fits that number of times in the second, not the other way around.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis I agree with your interpretation, and I commented as much to the question. That's why I answered this with "version of *your code*", because the question wasn't really about that, but about how to do `BigDecimal` calculations.

Comment: Sure, the answer is fine, just his interpretation of "fits into" is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can use BigDecimal like

```
BigDecimal a = BigDecimal.valueOf(10);
BigDecimal b = BigDecimal.valueOf(35.55);
BigDecimal c = b.divide(a, 3, BigDecimal.HALF_UP);
System.out.println(b + " / " + a + " = " + c);
```

Or you could use rounding like

```
System.out.printf("(int)(%.2f / %d) = %d%n", 35.55, 10, (int) (35.55 / 10));
System.out.printf("%.2f %% %d = %.2f%n", 35.55, 10, 35.55 % 10);
```

which prints

```
floor(35.55 / 10) = 3
35.55 % 10 = 5.55
```

Comment: Neither version prints the requested numbers of `3` and `5.55` (remainder).